# Change LibreOffice 5.4.2 UI font in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, fonts, libreoffice

I'm using LibreOffice 5.4.2 in Italian on Windows 7 Professional, and the menu font looks wrong. Often, the last character is clipped, which makes a B look like an E. When the last letter is a thin one - an I, i, or l - it is almost unreadable: some words, like "Grafici", appear as "Grafic", "Strumenti" is "Strument", and all o's almost look like c's.

[image]

I've tried looking in the documentation and for this version the option of using system UI fonts instead of LibreOffice's seems to be no longer available, which is a bit uncomfortable together with LO's poor choice of UI font.

I've looked in "Options - LibreOffice - View" but there I can only change icon sizes and style, mouse options, and hardware acceleration (I still tried all options for hardware acceleration just in case, but no joy).

There is a "Font Substitution" table but is disabled and empty. After some experimentation, there are only two nonproportional fonts that could be used in menus - Ebrima and Segoe UI (they have an "I" like that of Courier, unlike most other sans nonp fonts that have I's looking like pipe signs |). Unfortunately, font substitution only applies to font rendering within the document, not in the UI.

There's a Personalization theme where I'm asked which *Firefox* theme I want
- I left it at "do not use themes" (don't know why LibreOffice allows me to
change Firefox themes).

In the Application Colors sections I can only change colors, but I checked.

I verified that this is not caused by Font ClearType, and there are no relevant registry keys that might bear on the matter.

**Is there a way of changing LibreOffice UI font? Setting it to Windows defaults would be okay.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not strictly an answer since that version of LibreOffice still did not work for me.

But the new beta in English has no longer this problem, and I can live with that:

[image]